# Elliptic partial differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

Consider the following elliptic PDE:
$$
\Delta u=f(u),
$$
where $f(u)$ is a smooth function. Which references (books, papers,...etc.) about existence of solutions for this PDE do you recommend to have a rough introduction? In particular, I am interested in applying variation methods (Calculus of variations) to investigate the existence problem for this PDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start with Evans, "Partial Differential Equations." A good reference for general second-order elliptic equations is Gilbarg and Trudinger, "Elliptic Partial Differential Equations of Second Order."

Comment: Thank you for the information!